# What is the case for not creating journals in DB2 databases

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I come from the SQL server world so I don't know enough about DB2 to be dangerous.  I understand that to insert, update, delete records in DB2 from external sources such as SQL server, the underlying file in DB2 needs to be journaled.  We even have an application that uses JDBC to connect to DB2 and needs the file it inserts to be journaled (it is an instruction in the installation documentation)

My question is, why do DB2 DBA's not want any journals?  What is the case for why this is said?

I want to know the technical details of this rule of thumb.  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably off-topic...but there's really no good reason now-a-days.

Way back when the system 36/38 was born, commitment control wasn't a thing.

When the AS/400 was born, there were performance implications.  Many stayed away from using it.

Today, the only remotely valid reason is that there's a performance hit to batch jobs that update millions of records without using commitment control.

But there's an optional license program that takes care of that issue if need be;

> 57xx-ss1 option 42 i5/OS - HA Journal Performance.

The license program name comes from the fact that companies not currently journal usually run into the issue when they start journalling during an implementation of a HA solution that requires journalling.

Comment: This is what I suspected, I will wait a bit to see if anyone else chimes in.  Thank you

Comment: If it helps, note that if you create a schema (library) and table (file) using SQL DDL, the system will automatically start journalling for the table.

Comment: The momentum of legacy development practices is huge. So many files without journals. But I see more commitment control now than I used to.

Comment: Thatnks @Charles.  That fact that the programmers added automatic journalling in those cases speaks that its the norm.  Legacy momentum is interesting but annoying where ever i encounter it

Answer (score 0):

This is specific only to DB2 on IBM i (iSeries, AS/400), which began as an SQL language interface to the underlying sequential file access engine. Thus, SQL tables are implemented as files in the file system, which are not journaled by default. This is simply a legacy that carries on.

I believe tables (files) created using SQL (DDL) statements are journaled by default, as opposed to files created using DDS (data definition specs).

Comment: The AS/400 has always had an integrated relational DB.  As did its System 38 predecessor.  At it's introduction in 1988, the AS/400 supported both DDS and SQL interfaces into its RDMS.